# Spanning PHP files but method wont echo variables

Tags: php

This is a college assignment, so I know you wouldn't do this because it would be too easy to hack. I have searched so hard on this website too and I'm at a dead end. So here it is I have multiple PHP files where I am trying to pull variables across and print out hard coded user information. But my last login in function throws an error no matter what i change i keep getting different errors.This has to be done primarily with PHP and avoiding using SESSION. Any help or direction is appreciated.
My index form is straight forward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
</style>
<form action="method.php"; method="POST">
Name<input type="text" name="userName">
Password<input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my method.php is straight forward too and works.

```
<?php # person

$name1= $_POST['userName'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
//echo 'testclass.php#' . $name;

include 'testclass.php';

?>
```

But my method credentials won't work in this, it won't find name1 or password?

```
<?php

class UserController {
//private $name1;
//private $password;
private $isLoggedIn = false;

// Credentials
public function credentials() {
    $credentials = array(
        array(
            "username" => "Goat",
            "password" => "1234"
        ),
        array(
            "username" => "Goat",
            "password" => "1234"
        )
    );
    return $credentials;
}

// Basic login
public function login() {
    foreach ($this->credentials() as $credential) {
        //not finding name 1 and password even though its been called in this php file.
        if ($this->name1 == $credential['username'] && $this->password == $credential['password']) {
            $this->isLoggedIn = true;
        }
    }
if ($isLoggedIn = true){
    echo "YAYAYA";
}
else{
    echo "sad";
}
}
}
$user = new UserController();
$user->credentials();
$user->login();

?>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: A little comment with your downvote would go a long way.

Answer (score -1):

`$this->name1` does not exist as a class property. You cannot access those variables like that inside your UserController. You need to pass your parameters over to the login function.

```
public function login($username, $password) 
{
    foreach ($this->credentials() as $credential) 
    {
        if ($username == $credential['username'] && $password == $credential['password']) {
            $this->isLoggedIn = true;
        }
    }
}

$user = new UserController();
$user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
```